Get differnt UAC_GetIntegrityLevel value with current NSIS installer version
After upgrading NSIS installer software from version 2.46 to 3.09 and usage of the same scripts on same computer we get different UAC_GetIntegrityLevel value:
NSIS 2.46:
UAC_GetIntegrityLevel=0x3000
NSIS 3.09:
UAC_GetIntegrityLevel=0x0
What has changed?
We upgrade NSIS installer software and UAC plugin

Are you compiling as Ansi or Unicode in v3? Did you copy the correct plug-in to the correct plug-in sub folder?

I did not specify anything during compilation, so I guess to use ANSI.

And I also copied the latest UAC plugin to all sub folders (plugins, x86-ansi, x86-unicode)

NSIS v3.09 is Unicode by default.
If the problem is fixed by adding Unicode False to the top of your .nsi then you put the wrong UAC.dll in NSIS\Plugins\x86-unicode or your .nsi has !addplugindir ".\plugins\x86-ansi" somewhere in it.
